# server space on linux server

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to find the diskspace available on workspace2 by using "df -h" command..it gives the following output...how do I know what is the free space available on workspace2?

```
<user:/local/mnt>ls
workspace  workspace2
<user:/local/mnt>df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             9.2G  5.1G  3.7G  59% /
none                  5.9G  308K  5.9G   1% /dev
none                  5.9G   64K  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
none                  5.9G  6.7M  5.9G   1% /var/run
none                  5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /var/lock
none                  5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda1             938M   61M  830M   7% /boot
/dev/sda3             3.7G  1.4G  2.2G  38% /var
/dev/sda6             122G   69G   48G  60% /local
/dev/sdb1             917G  713G  158G  82% /local/mnt2
/dev/sda7             9.2G  7.7G  1.1G  88% /usr/vice/cache
AFS                   8.6G     0  8.6G   0% /afs
sheraton:/vol/vol2/usr2/c_mkoyya
                  2.0T  1.9T  125G  94% /usr2/c_koyam
 sheraton:/vol/vol2/usr2/mkhanna
                  2.0T  1.9T  125G  94% /usr2/mkanan
freeze:/vol/eng_asw_0043/l4linux
                  200G  197G  3.7G  99% /prj/l4linux
watercooler:/vol/watercooler_vol0/watercooler/usr2/gnkala
                  3.0T  2.3T  742G  76% /usr2/gnkala
westin:/vol/vol2/usr2/longjunl
                  2.0T  1.9T   67G  97% /usr2/longjunl
sheraton:/vol/vol2/usr2/shanem
                  2.0T  1.9T  125G  94% /usr2/shanem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `df -h /local/mnt/workspace2/.` That will make sure you check the actual filesystem containing that directory, resolving through any mount points, symbolic links, etc...

Comment: I never knew you could specify any directory there. Very handy, thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

`/mnt/local/` is a normal directory in your mount `/local` which is located on `/dev/sda6` so you have 48GB free space.

Answer (score 0):

```
df -P /local/mnt/workspace2 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $4 }'
```